# Auto Wifi logout

Tags: wi-fi

When I login to my home wifi network through my LG G2, the login page dies as soon as I minimize that window. I have tried logging in with chrome, firefox, opera but the same problem persists. The login page should be active all the time, otherwise it logs out after 30minutes. So how can I keep that login page alive in the browser ? The system works fine in my laptop and even in my nokia phone, which allows me to minimize that login window, but android phone doesn't. Kindly tell me the solution.